# Replace double for each by observable

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming

I have two lists: `List<Foo>` and `List<Bar>`. For each item of `List<Foo>`, I have to check all items of `List<Bar>`, and set a value if it's are matching. Today I'm using this code:

```
fooList.forEach { foo ->
   barList.forEach { bar ->
        if(foo.id == bar.id) {
            bar.name = foo.name
        }
    }
}
return barList
```

I want to change it, because now I have an `Observable<Foo>` and an `Observable<Bar>`. 
How could I replace my code to use the reactive programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could collect the `Bar`s into a `Map` of id to name and run foo sequence with it:

```
Observable<Bar> bars = ...
Observable<Foo> foos = ...

bars
    .toMap(bar -> bar.id, bar -> bar.name)
    .flatMap(map -> 
        foos.doOnNext(foo -> {
            String name = map.get(foo.id);
            if (name != null) {
                foo.name = name;
            }
        })
    )
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: It's not working because in some cases the Observable<Bar> are empty, and the Observable<Foo> aren't. When it happens anything is emmited

Comment: If bars is empty, how do you expect to match it with a non-empty foo?

Comment: if it's empty, so all foo's will be the older name, but they have to be emitted

Comment: Observable.toMap always emits a Map so the foos will always be streamed.